# Turning a Presence/Absence Matrix into a Cluster Analysis in R Studio

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

Okay, I have a presence/absence matrix of 6 samples with 25 possibilities of presence/absence.

I've been able to make a cluster dendrogram with the data, but I'd rather have it plotted as a distance matrix that looks better and is easier to analysis? (Maybe a cluster plot or something similar?)

I'm really stuck with figuring out the next part - I've spent days searching on here and various other Google searches but nothing is turning up!

Here's the code I've got for the cluster dendrogram:

```
matrix<-read.csv("Horizontal.csv")
distance<-dist(matrix)
hc.m<-hclust(distance)
plot(hc.m, labels=matrix$Sample, main ="", cex.main=0.8, cex.lab= 1.1)
```

Help!

```
> dput(head(matrix,20))structure(list(Sample = structure(1:6, .Label =     c("CL1", "CL2", 
"CL3", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3"), class = "factor"), X = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X.3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.4 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X.5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X.6 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.7 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.8 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.10 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.11 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.12 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.13 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X.14 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.16 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X.17 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.18 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.19 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.20 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.21 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X.22 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X.23 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X.24 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Sample", "X", "X.1", "X.2", 
"X.3", "X.4", "X.5", "X.6", "X.7", "X.8", "X.9", "X.10", "X.11", 
"X.12", "X.13", "X.14", "X.15", "X.16", "X.17", "X.18", "X.19", 
"X.20", "X.21", "X.22", "X.23", "X.24"), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Okay with this code:

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)
#set working directory
setwd("~/Documents/Masters/BS707/Metagenomics")
#read csv file
cookie<-read.csv("Horizontal.csv")
data.frame(cookie, row.names = c("CL1", "CL2", "CL3", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3"))
df = subset(cookie)
data.frame(df, row.names = c("CL1", "CL2", "CL3", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3"))
dm<- dist(df, method = "binary")  #calculate the distance matrix
cmdscale(dm, eig = TRUE, k=2) -> mds
as.tibble(mds$points)  #mds coordinates
bind_cols(df, Sample = df$Sample)  #bind sample names  
mutate(df,group = gsub("\\d$", "", "Sample1"))#remove last digit from   sample names to form groups
ggplot(df)+
 geom_point (aes(x = "V1",y = "V2", color = "group")) #plot
as.tibble(mds$points) %>% ggplot() + geom_point (aes(x = V1, y = V2))
```

I get the plot but each group is named 'Sample' rather than CL1, CL2, CL3, COL1, COL2, COL3. I had to remove the %>% because my R didn't recognise it as a command or anything and gave an error every single time (switched to + or deleted and then it worked fine).

Comment: Could you provide how your plot would looks like?

Comment: Is there a way to plot it so you have similarities along the axis (similar to the units of an NMDS plot) with the 6 samples labelled as individual points? I'm really struggling to figure out the best way to present it. Sorry if thats no help!

Comment: perhaps euclidean distance is not the best way to calculate distance for binary data. Try `dist(matrix, method="binary")` it will compute the Jaccard distance. If you would like to plot the distance matrix it in 2 dimensions take a look at NMDS for instance in `library(vegan)` `metaMDS`

Comment: @missuse thank you!! I'll have a look :)

Comment: @EmilyDelva nobody likes to type text based on an image. Please use the command `dput(head(matrix, 20))` and paste the result to the post.

Comment: @missuse wasn't sure if you needed it to look/or take parts my bad! Its added now

Comment: @missuse done that, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to visualize your data in 2 dimensions:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  dplyr::select(-1) %>% #remove first column
  dist(method = "binary") %>% #calculate the distance matrix
  cmdscale(eig = TRUE, k = 2) -> mds #do MDS also known as principal coordinates analysis

as.tibble(mds$points) %>% #mds coordinates
  bind_cols( Sample = df$Sample) %>% #bind sample names
  mutate(group = gsub("\\d$", "", Sample)) %>% #remove last digit from sample names to form groups
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x = V1,y = V2, color = group)) #plot
```

or without tidyverse:

```
df_dist <- dist(df[,-1], method = "binary") 
mds <- cmdscale(df_dist, eig = TRUE, k = 2) 

for_plot <- data.frame(mds$points, group = gsub("\\d$", "", df$Sample))

ggplot(for_plot)+
  geom_point(aes(x = X1,y = X2, color = group))
```

[image]

other options include using `isoMDS` from `MASS` library which will perform Kruskal's Non-metric Multidimensional Scaling or `metaMDS` from `vegan` library which performs Nonmetric Multidimensional Scaling with Stable Solution from Random Starts, Axis Scaling and Species Scores.

Comment: Trying this now at home and I've got two errors coming up that I don't understand - one is 

"Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"" - assuming here I need to change the class of the data?

and then

"Error in as.tibble(mds$points) : object 'mds' not found" - have I missed installing a package for this?